# Is $\lim x_n^n=c\in R^+$ then $\lim x_n=1$ true?

Tags: limits

As title, is it true that when $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n^n=c \in R^+$ is a positive real number (and thus finite), is it necessary/true that $\lim_{n \to\infty} x_n=1$? It seems to make sense to me, and <s>I believe I have a proof, but I am unsure about it, so may someone proof-read/point out my mistake, or parts that require more proving?</s> As mentioned in the comments, my "proof" is based on $\lim x_n^n=(\lim x_n)^n$, which is simply not true, as the limit is taken with respect to $n$.

Thank you.

Comment: The $\lim x_n^n  = (\lim x_n )^n$ equality is not correct since the limit is taken with respect to $n$. Instead, let $\varepsilon>0$ such that $c>1+\varepsilon$. Since $x_n \to c$, there is an $N$ (depending on $\varepsilon$) such that for all $n>N$, $(1 < )c - \varepsilon  < x_n  (< c +\varepsilon)$. Can you continue from here? The other cases are similar.

Comment: Ah I see... one example would be $x_n=1+\frac{1}{n}$ and $\lim x_n^n=e\neq 1$, correct?

Comment: In that example your $c=1$ and not bigger than $1$.

Comment: For "The other cases are similar", do you mean for when $c<1$ and $c=1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \log x_n^n=\lim_{n\to\infty} 
n\log x_n=\log c$$
Thus $\log x_n\to 0$, so $x_n\to 1$.

Comment: I would accept this answer, because it's the more elegant one (and simplest I would say).

Comment: Slightly different way to say the same is $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \log x_n  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {\frac{1}{n}n\log x_n } \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{n}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } (n\log x_n ) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{n}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } (\log x^n_n ) \\ = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{n} (\log (\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty }x^n_n) ) = 0 \cdot \log c = 0,
$$i.e., $\mathop {\lim }_{n \to  + \infty } x_n=1$.

Comment: How do you conclude $\log x_n\to 0$ from $n\log x_n\to\log c$?

Answer (score 2):

If $(x_n^n)$ converges to some $c>0$, then starting from some index, this sequence lands entirely in the neighbourhood $(c/2,\ 2c)$ of the point $c$ in $\Bbb R$. So we have the squeeze:
$$
c/2\le x_n^n\le 2c\ ,\text{ i.e.}
$$
$$
\sqrt[n]{c/2}\le x_n\le \sqrt[n]{2c}\ ,
$$
starting from that index. Because the sequence $(x_n)$ is in the sandwich of two sequences converging to one, it also converges to one.

Comment: I would accept Matt's answer, since his idea and proof is overall simpler, though this answer is also elegant and more formal and rigorous. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma:** If $p > 0$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{p} = 1$.

If the sequence $\{x_n^n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of powers converges to some positive real number $c$, then letting $p = c/2$ and $q = 3c/2$, and picking the specific error $\varepsilon = c/2>0$, for sufficiently large indices $n$ we will have

$p = c - \varepsilon < x_n^n < c + \varepsilon = q$.

Thus, eventually $\sqrt[n]{p} < x_n < \sqrt[n]{q}$, whence by the squeeze theorem, $x_n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: The lemma is true because if $0<p<1$, it can be written as $p=\frac{1}{q}$ with $q>1$, then when $p>1$, it is trivial, correct?

Comment: I would accept Matt's answer, since his idea and proof is overall simpler, though this answer is also elegant and more formal and rigorous. Thank you!