# If $(t_n^n)$ is convergent, does it hold $t_n\to1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq(0,\infty)$ such that $t_n^n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}t$ for some $t>0$. Can we conclude that $t_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1$?

This seems obvious, but how can we prove it?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3609497/42969.

Comment: Nope. Pick $t_n=0$.

Comment: Or suppose $t_n= 1$ if $n$ is odd and $t_n=-1$ if $n$ is even. Then, $t_n^n=1$ for all $n$, even though $\{t_n\} $ doesn't have a limit. You should assume for example each $t_n>0$ (which is what was done in the accepted answer in the link above).

Comment: It becomes true if you (as in the question linked by MartinR) assume $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} t_n^n>0$ and $t_n>0$. Clearly you can pick any sequence that goes to zero and then also powers will go to zero.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks for noting; edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Isn't is now exactly what MartinR linked?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Ho does the accepted answer conclude $\log x_n\to 0$ from $n\log x_n\to\log c$?

Comment: Because $\log(x_n)=\frac{1}{n} \log(x_n^n)$, which converges to zero.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Well, clearly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $t_n^n \to t$ then $$t-\varepsilon \leq t^n_n \leq t+\varepsilon$$
for sufficiently large $n.$
hence $$1\leftarrow\sqrt[n]{t-\varepsilon }\leq t_n \leq \sqrt[n]{t+\varepsilon }\to 1$$